# Subtract date from macro variable

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro

I'm having trouble subtracting a date from a Macro Variable.

Currently, I create a macro variable by running:

```
%LET date = %SYSFUNC(TODAY(),MMDDYY10.);
```

I feel like I should be able to subtract 1 day from **&date** by doing the following:

```
%LET newDate = %SYSFUNC(%INTNX('day',&date,-1),date9.);
```

However, this produces the error:

**ERROR: Function name missing in %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function reference.**

I need the output for **&newDate** to be in **date9.**

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
%LET date = %SYSFUNC(TODAY()); 
%LET newDate = %SYSFUNC(INTNX(day,&date,-1),date9.);
%put &=newdate;
```

**Explanation:**

Firstly, best to remove the formatting from `&date` to ensure it is interpreted correctly as a date.  Your original code resolved (today) inside `intnx()` to 12/06/2016, which then resolved to 12 divided by 6 divided by 2016 - etc.

Secondly, the inner function to `%sysfunc()` should be a datastep function - indeed, the whole point of `%sysfunc()` is to bring these functions into sas. `%intnx()` isn't a macro function, but if if was, then by definition you wouldn't need to wrap it in `%sysfunc()`.

Finally, the 'day' parameter shouldn't be quoted - everything in sas macro is treated as text by default.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer. I pushed everything I needed to do into a data step and got the desired output. Long story short, don't try to do all this on one line, use a data step.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting I see no reason not to do this in the macro langauge generally speaking, you just didn't understand it properly - but if you don't understand the macro language, that's a good reason to put it in a data step for sure!

Comment: @Joe Fair. I can't argue with that! (Came back years later since SO notified me about 1,000 views on the question today.)

Answer (score 0):

@RawFocus, you are correct that there is no need to format the original date (today's date), and it is easier to deal with that way.

Just for completeness, if someone wanted to apply the `MMDDYY10.` format, this is how it could be done:

```
%LET date = %SYSFUNC(TODAY(),mmddyy10.); 
%LET newDate = %SYSFUNC(INTNX(day,%SYSFUNC(INPUTN(&date,mmddyy10)),-1),date9.);
%put &=date &=newdate;
```